# Write number of rows based on array

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I post multiple checkboxes values from a form as cities[]. If I print array it looks like this:

```
Array ( [0] => 8 [1] => 9 [2] => 16 [3] => 18 [4] => 19 [5] => 25 [6] => 60 )
```

Number of checkboxes checked can vary from one to 200 and I need to write each value on a different row in mysql table 'cities'. Eg. 10 checkboxes checked = 10 rows. I also need to add same 'user_id' on each row.

```
$user_id = '12345'; // this I can get from session
```

My database table 'cities' structure:   `id(auto increment), city_id, user_id`

I need save data like this:

1st row: id=1, city_id=8, user_id=12345

2nd row: id=2, city_id=9, user_id=12345

and so on...

I tried this:

```
foreach(($_POST['cities'] as $c) {
  $query = 'INSERT INTO cities values (null, \'' . $c['id'] . '\', \'' . $c['city_id'] . '\', '$user_id');'
  mysql_query($query);
}
```

I think I'm lost. Thanks for any help.

Comment: Do not use `MySQL_\*` functions as they have been deprecated, use `MySQLi_\*` or PDO. Also, what errors do you get? `mysql_error`

Answer (score 0):

```
    foreach(($_POST['cities'] as $c) {    
          $query = "INSERT INTO cities(city_id, user_id) values ('$c', '$user_id');"    
          mysql_query($query);    
    }
```

I believe you only need to run above query

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach($_POST['cities'] as $city_id) {
   $query = "INSERT INTO cities VALUES(0, ${city_id}, $user_id)";
   mysql_query($query);
}
```

This should run x queries based on the passed cities array. Due to the auto incrementing id you just need to put a '0' as city_id.

Keep in mind to protect your queries from sql injection by using the proper functions and sanitization of your inputs.

Answer (score 0):

Inserting multiple rows is done like so:

```
INSERT INTO example
VALUES
  (100, 'Name 1', 'Value 1', 'Other 1'),
  (101, 'Name 2', 'Value 2', 'Other 2'),
  (102, 'Name 3', 'Value 3', 'Other 3'),
  (103, 'Name 4', 'Value 4', 'Other 4');
```

See: http://www.electrictoolbox.com/mysql-insert-multiple-records/

Your loop should look something like

```
$query = "INSERT INTO cities ";

foreach($_POST['cities'] as $key => $value) {
  $query .= "values (null, '" . $c['id'] . "', '" . $c['city_id'] . "', ".$user_id."), ";
}

// take last comma off
$query = substr($query, -2);

mysql_query($query);
```

P.S. Watch your syntax errors!